# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ¿Qué significa?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo una base de datos con las siguientes tablas y datos

```
  CREATE TABLE "AEROPUERTOS" 
   (    "CN_AERO" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "ID_AERO" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "CIU_ID_CIUDAD" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
   )
Insert into AEROPUERTOS (CN_AERO,ID_AERO,CIU_ID_CIUDAD) values ('El Prat','BCN','1');
Insert into AEROPUERTOS (CN_AERO,ID_AERO,CIU_ID_CIUDAD) values ('Barajas','MDR','2');
Insert into AEROPUERTOS (CN_AERO,ID_AERO,CIU_ID_CIUDAD) values ('Valencia','VLC','3');
Insert into AEROPUERTOS (CN_AERO,ID_AERO,CIU_ID_CIUDAD) values ('Sevilla','SVL','4');

  CREATE TABLE "CIUDADES" 
   (    "ID_CIUDAD" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE), 
    "CN_CIUDAD" VARCHAR2(25 BYTE), 
    "PAI_ID_PAIS" VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)
   ) 
Insert into CIUDADES (ID_CIUDAD,CN_CIUDAD,PAI_ID_PAIS) values ('1','Barcelona','1');
Insert into CIUDADES (ID_CIUDAD,CN_CIUDAD,PAI_ID_PAIS) values ('2','Madrid','1');
Insert into CIUDADES (ID_CIUDAD,CN_CIUDAD,PAI_ID_PAIS) values ('3','Valencia','1');
```

Estoy haciendo un trigger que añada a la tabla aeropuertos una nueva fila después de insertar en la tabla ciudades una nueva ciudad. La fila nueva que se crea en la tabla aeropuertos debe crear el identificador (CN_AERO) del nuevo aeropuerto como las tres primeras letras del nombre de la ciudad, el código de la ciudad y el nombre del aeropuerto debe ser ‘Nuevo Aero de NOMBRE_CIUDAD’.

Ejemplo: Si la ciudad insertada es (120, Verona), entonces el código de inserción del aeropuerto es:
Identificador: VER
Nombre: Nuevo Aero de VERONA
Ciudad: 120

Al hacer el trigger, no me envía un mensaje de error, el trigger se crea correctamente

```
create or replace trigger Nuevo_Aeropuerto
after insert
on ciudades
for each row
declare
    PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
    ID_AERO varchar2(10);
begin
    select SUBSTR(:new.CN_CIUDAD,1,2) into ID_AERO from ciudades;
    insert into aeropuertos values ('El nuevo aero de '||:new.CN_CIUDAD,ID_AERO,:new.ID_CIUDAD);
end;
```

Pero cuando intento insertar el valor en la nueva tabla ciudades, me marca un error "exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows", ¿Qué significa?.

```
insert into ciudades values ('31','VERONA','3');
```

[image: Error]

Al probar diferentes cosas me di cuenta que el error estaba en guardar los primeros 3 caracteres de una palabra en una variable local pero no lo pude solucionar.

Comment: Consultar la tabla CIUDADES dentro de un trigger de la misma tabla es una mala práctica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que al decir from ciudades;

```
select SUBSTR(:new.CN_CIUDAD,1,2) into ID_AERO from ciudades;
```

Traes por cada ciudad la columna SUBSTR(:new.CN_CIUDAD,1,2). Si tienes 3 ciudades tendrías 3 filas con esos datos. No puedes insertar esas 3 filas en ID_AERO porque es un varchar.

Si quieres almacenar el valor en ID_AERO simplemente tienes que usar :=

```
ID_AERO := SUBSTR(:new.CN_CIUDAD,1,2)
```

Si lo que quieres es obtener algun dato de la ciudad te faltaría el where para que la consulta solo te traiga el registro de la que se acaba de almacenar:

```
  select SUBSTR(:new.CN_CIUDAD,1,2) into ID_AERO from ciudades where ID_CIUDAD = :new.ID_CIUDAD;
```

Esto último no tiene mucho sentido porque ya con :new tienes todos los datos del nuevo registro de ciudad pero lo dejo para que veas el error en el select into.

Comment: comenta sobre el nuevo error

Comment: Si dejo el ID_AERO como tú lo declaraste y luego le inserto el nuevo valor en ciudades, me marca el siguiente error: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource –

Comment: Ya no hace falta, el error era en PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
Con eliminarlo bastó para que se solucionara el problema.

Comment: ah, genial que pudiste resolver, saludos.